# vertical aligment for span element

Tags: css

I'm getting some problems with vertical aligment.
I want to put my `<span>›</span>` element centralized in vertical.
http://jsfiddle.net/vpVEf/

Is there a way to centralize it automatically as the "li a" in this example? Note that the a element is centralized without using line-height.
http://jsfiddle.net/vpVEf/9/

Comment: Hi everyone. I still have a doubt about this issue. s there a way to centralize it automatically as the "li a" in this example? Note that the a element is centralized without using line-height. http://jsfiddle.net/vpVEf/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the `a` tag has a padding, pushing down everything in it by 12px.

Remove the top/bottom padding and use `line-height` to make it `68px` tall.

```
padding: 0 12px;
line-height: 68px;
```

It might not look like it, but this *does* fix the problem. Remove all formatting from the `span` to see! But now the issue is that the text isn't aligned center within the span. You can use `line-height` on the `span` to adjust that as well.

```
line-height: 55px;
```

Seems to work well.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vpVEf/7/)

Comment: Hi everyone. I still have a doubt about this issue. s there a way to centralize it automatically as the "li a" in this example? Note that the a element is centralized without using line-height. jsfiddle.net/vpVEf/9

Comment: No it's not. You have `line-height` on the `li`. The `span` is floating though so it doesn't get affected by that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using line-height to adjust the vertical alignment on your span:

```
#MenuEventos li span{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    color: white;
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: auto 0px auto 0px;
    line-height: 44px; /* Adjust this as needed */
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vpVEf/1/

Comment: s there a way to centralize it automatically as the "li a" in this example? Note that the a element is centralized without using line-height. http://jsfiddle.net/vpVEf/9/

Answer (score 0):

Take the `line-height: 2.8em;` that you have in `#MenuEventos li a` style and move it to the  `#MenuEventos li` style.

See this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zFnJb/

Answer (score -1):

You need to make `<a>` element floating left and `<span>` element floating right.